# WS-Security Policy node not being generated in Apache CXF with Spring and custom context file

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl, cxf, ws-security

I have an SOAP web service generated with Apache CXF and using Spring. The interface was generated from a WSDL without WS-Security Policy. Now I need to include this WS-Security node in the generated WSDL:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" wsu:Id="wss_saml_or_username_token_service_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:SamlToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssSamlV11Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:SamlToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I included this dependencies in maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-rm</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I included this annotation in my service implementation

```
@Policies({
        @Policy(uri = "SecurityPolicy.xml")
}
)
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://sample.com/SampleService", name = "SampleService", portName = "SampleService_pt")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I modified the Spring context file to include cxf context files like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-policy.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-ws-security.xml"/>
```

I created a file named SecurityPolicy.xml under my WEB-INF directory with the security policy content like this:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" wsu:Id="wss_saml_or_username_token_service_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:SamlToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssSamlV11Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:SamlToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Howhever, I'm still not getting the WS-Security Policy node in the generated WSDL.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. I had to make some modifications.

First, move SecurityPolicy.xml to the **resources** directory, then modify the **@Policy** annotation to get the policy file from the classpath:

```
@Policies({
        @Policy(uri = "classpath:SecurityPolicy.xml",
                placement = Policy.Placement.BINDING)
}
)
```

Comment: I followed your solution here, but it still didn't add policy in wsdl document. Did you do anything else?